# Network Status Detect In Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new in Reactjs my problem is that i have to detect the network status if wifi or internet connection is connected or disconnected

i tried using the below code but it wont detect network status correctly it always return false value

please help me

and here is my code and [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-dewdney-fk5tg?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('online', () => setStatus(navigator.onLine))
    return () => window.removeEventListener('online', () => setStatus(navigator.onLine))
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Network Status Detector</h2>
      {status ? <div style={{ top: 50, position: "absolute" }}>Network Connected</div> : <div style={{ top: 50, position: "absolute"}}>Network Disconnected</div>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the same function reference for the event listener else it won't clean up on unmount/effect cleanup.

Here's a sample code for this

```
export default function App() {
  return <NetworkStatus />;
}
const NetworkStatus = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    function changeStatus() {
      setStatus(navigator.onLine);
    }
    window.addEventListener("online", changeStatus);
    window.addEventListener("offline", changeStatus);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("online", changeStatus);
      window.removeEventListener("offline", changeStatus);
    };
  }, []);

  return status ? "Online" : "Offline";
};
```

Look how we're not using an arrow function here. We can either create the function inside the useEffect or a function returned by useCallback.

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-cache-50wg5?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

There is an online and an offline event from the window object.
You should be able to attach two listeners to the window like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('online', () => setStatus(true))
  window.addEventListener('offline', () => setStatus(false))
}, [])
```

Comment: Also pls use default value as `true` 
Create a function using useCallback to be passed to the eventListener and use the same in removeEvent listner

Comment: You're supposed to use `useEffect()` [with clean-up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) to remove event listeners as component gets unmounted.